# keyup event resets input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Every time I press a key on my keyboard, it sets `$(this).val("");` to null and the `score` variable will be -2.

```
initialize: function() {
    var score = 0;
    var wrapper = $('<div>')
        .css({
            position:'fixed',
            top:'0',
            left:'0',
            width:'100%',
            height:'100%'
        });
    this.wrapper = wrapper;

    var self = this;
    var text_input = $('<input>')
        .addClass('form-control')
        .css({
            'border-radius':'4px',
            position:'absolute',
            bottom:'0',
            'min-width':'80%',
            width:'80%',
            'margin-bottom':'10px',
            'z-index':'1000'
        }).keyup(function() {
            var words = self.model.get('words');
            for(var i = 0;i < words.length;i++) {
                var word = words.at(i);
                var typed_string = $(this).val();
                var string = word.get('string');
                if(string.toLowerCase().indexOf(typed_string.toLowerCase()) === 0) {
                    word.set({highlight:typed_string.length});
                    if(typed_string.length === string.length) {
                        $(this).val("");
                        score+=10;
                        $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'title', 'Score : '+score);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    word.set({highlight:0});
                    $(this).val(""); // problem
                    score-=2; // problem
                    $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'title', 'Score : '+score); // problem
                }
            }
        });

    $(this.el)
        .append(wrapper
            .append($('<form>')
                .attr({
                    role:'form'
                })
                .submit(function() {
                    return false;
                })
                .append(text_input)));

    text_input.css({left:((wrapper.width() - text_input.width()) / 2) + 'px'});
    text_input.focus();

    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
},
```

When I remove the code that causes the problem, it works perfectly every time. inputting the right word and giving the `var score` score of +10.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you explain what do you wish to achieve?

Comment: I'm already uploaded to this link http://benndoll.coffee/test/. for javascript code can check at http://benndoll.coffee/test/typer.js . the problem, when i'm putting code in else statement, and type any word in inputext, value $(this).val(""); always become null and score always -2 too.

Comment: Your question should be self contained. Please include a [mcve] which you can easily achieve with a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How the `keyup` event works?

The `keyup` event is triggered every time a key is released.

This means that if the target word is `haromy`, when typing the `h`, the event is triggered and the code in the callback is run.

It means that the following will always be false if typing the first letter wrong.

```
"haromy".toLowerCase().indexOf("f".toLowerCase()) === 0
```

So the user types a letter, it's not the same first letter, so the field is emptied immediatly by `$(this).val("")`.

### Maybe use another event?

If you want to check once the user unfocus the input, the `blur` event would work.

If you want to make the check when the user clicks a button, use a click event on a new button.

## How to stylize a JavaScript application?

Do not set the initial CSS using jQuery's `css` function. Keep the styling in a CSS file linked in the HTML.

Using the `css` function only clutters your application logic, makes it difficult to maintain and delay the application of the style to after the JavaScript execution.

## How to bind jQuery events with Backbone?

*I removed the [backbone.js](/questions/tagged/backbone.js) tag from the question as it's irrelevant, but seeing that you're using it and that it could be improved a lot, I'll throw additional information here.*

When using Backbone, don't bind events using jQuery directly. Use the Backbone view's `events` hash.

Your view could look like this:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: '<div class="wrapper"><input class="form-control" /></div>'
    events: {
        "blur input": "onInputBlur"
    },
    onInputBlur: function() {
        var words = this.model.get('words').each(function(word) {
            var typed_string = this.$input.val(),
                string = word.get('string');
            // Check each word and score here
        }, this);
    },


    initialize: function() {
        this.score = 0;
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template);
        this.$wrapper = this.$('.wrapper');
        this.$input = this.$('input').focus();
        return this;
    },
});
```

With styles out, the CSS file would be:

```
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.input {
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```